# Can the data between Express.js middleware be manipulated/tampered in any way?

Tags: javascript, man-in-the-middle, jwt, confidentiality, node.js

In the `node.js` `express.js` framework there is middleware support. Let's assume I have two middleware - the first one, which verifies whether the JWT token is legit and not tampered with and the second middleware which doesn't verify anymore whether it's legit and just entends the expiration date of it.

My question is rather simple:

- Can the connection between the two middleware be somehow tampered with/manipulated?